# Create a dictionary from a csv file with same value

Tags: python

I have a csv file formatted the following way. I would like to create a dynamic dictionary with the `price` being the key and all the names with the same `price` in the csv being in its array even the duplicate names. I tried a way but it only return one value per price because I don't know how to append data within a list comprehension.

```
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price2;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price2;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price2;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price3;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price3;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price3;2,00;;private-code
```

```py
class Parse:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.data = {}

    def openFile(self):
        with open(self.file, newline='') as csvfile:
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
            self.data = {row[5]:row[3] for row in spamreader}
            print(self.data)
            # for row in spamreader:
            #     self.data[row[5]] =
            #     print("email of user => {}".format(row[1]))
            #     print("Last name of user => {}".format(row[2]))
            #     print("Name of user => {}".format(row[3]))
            #     print("Prices => {}".format(row[5]))
```

Comment: use normal `for`-loop instead of list comprehension.

Comment: if you would use `pandas.DataFrame` then you could use `df.groupby(column)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use normal `for`-loop for this

```
for row in spamreader:
    if row[5] not in self.data:
          self.data[row[5]] = []

    self.data[row[5]].append(row[3])
    #self.data[row[5]].append(row)
```

---

Eventually you could use `defaultdict` and `list` as default value - and it will automatically create empty list when it will be needed.

```
 import collections

 self.data = collections.defaultdict(list)


 for row in spamreader:
     self.data[row[5]].append(row[3])
```

---

**BTW:**

Standard module `itertools` has function [groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which probably could be also useful but I never used it.

`pandas.DataFrame` has also `groupby()` which can be useful. And it can read `csv`.

I use `io.StringIO` only to simulate file in memory. You should use `filename`

```
text = '''19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price2;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price2;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price2;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price3;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price3;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price3;2,00;;private-code
'''

import pandas as pd

import io

#df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", header=None, sep=';')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), header=None, sep=';')

#df.iloc[:,5]

for value, group in df.groupby(5):
    print('--- value:', value, '---')
    print(group)
```

Result:

```
--- value: price1 ---
                      0                       1  ...   7             8
0   19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
1   19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
2   19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
3   19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
4   19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
5   19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
6   19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
7   19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
8   19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
9   19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
10  19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
11  19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
12  19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
13  19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code
14  19/06/2021 18:18:17  people-mail@hotmail.fr  ... NaN  private-code

[15 rows x 9 columns]

--- value: price2 ---
                      0                      1  ...   7             8
15  15/06/2021 12:43:59  people-mail@gmail.com  ... NaN  private-code
16  15/06/2021 12:43:59  people-mail@gmail.com  ... NaN  private-code
17  15/06/2021 12:43:59  people-mail@gmail.com  ... NaN  private-code

[3 rows x 9 columns]

--- value: price3 ---
                      0                      1  ...   7             8
18  15/06/2021 12:43:59  people-mail@gmail.com  ... NaN  private-code
19  15/06/2021 12:43:59  people-mail@gmail.com  ... NaN  private-code
20  15/06/2021 12:43:59  people-mail@gmail.com  ... NaN  private-code

[3 rows x 9 columns]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example with other mentioned methods

```
text = '''19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
19/06/2021 18:18:17;people-mail@hotmail.fr;lastname;firstname;Validé;price1;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price2;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price2;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price2;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price3;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price3;2,00;;private-code
15/06/2021 12:43:59;people-mail@gmail.com;lastname;firstname;Validé;price3;2,00;;private-code
'''

import csv
import io

# ---

data = {}

#with open('filename.csv') as fh:
with io.StringIO(text) as fh:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=';')

    for row in csv_reader:
        if row[5] not in data:
            data[row[5]] = []

        data[row[5]].append(row[3])

for key, value in data.items():
    print(key, value)
print('---')

# ---

import collections

data = collections.defaultdict(list)

#with open('filename.csv') as fh:
with io.StringIO(text) as fh:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=';')

    for row in csv_reader:
        data[row[5]].append(row[3])

for key, value in data.items():
    print(key, value)
print('---')
                
# ---

import collections
import itertools

data = collections.defaultdict(list)


#with open('filename.csv') as fh:
with io.StringIO(text) as fh:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=';')

    all_rows = list(csv_reader)
    data = itertools.groupby(all_rows, key=lambda row:row[5])

for key, value in data:
    print(key)
    for item in value:
        print(item)
print('---')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the output you're looking for but the code supplied has a number or errors. Instead of running through them I've rewritten it below.

```py
class Parse:
    def __init__( self, file ):
        self.file = file
        self.data = {}

    def openFile(self, x ):
        with open( self.file, mode='rt') as csvfile:
            self.spamreader = csvfile.read( )
        self.spam = self.spamreader.split('\n')
        self.spam.remove('')
        for a in self.spam:
            b = a.split(';')
            if b[5] in self.data:
                self.data[b[5]].append(b[x])
            else:
                self.data[b[5]] = [ b[x] ]
        print( self.data )
        

A = Parse('mycsv.csv')
A.openFile(3)
```

select the column required when opening file